# TFS 2018 Stakeholder role

Tags: tfs

My TFS installation in on premise and I would like to add users to a project allowing them to create and edit work items, but not work as a developer who can create branches or check in code.  Is there a default group like that?

I do not see anything in the permission list that mentions code rights.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what the [stakeholder access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) is for. Access levels are different from security groups. Stakeholders don't even have the ability to *see* the Code tab.

Comment: I have seen that mentioned, but do not see that listed as an available group.  Is that for the online version only?  Is there an on premise equivalent?

Comment: Stakeholder **is not a group**. It is an **access level**. It exists in both Azure DevOps/VSTS and on-prem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Comment: I see the access level.  If someone has already been added to a team, will added that person to the Stakeholder access level update what they can see?

Comment: @Nick What's your default access level? If it's higher than stakeholder, then putting someone in stakeholder will downgrade their access. If your default access level is stakeholder, putting someone in stakeholder will do nothing.